# Matplotlib: numbers in xaxis are shown disordered

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to plot a simple diagram from a file, having time in xaxis and ms of responses in yaxis. So, I have this code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

lines = [line.strip() for line in open('pingLog.txt')]

time = []
ms = []
for i, x in enumerate(lines):
    t, m = x.split(',')
    time.append(t)
    ms.append(m)

plt.plot(time, ms)
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

The 'pingLog.txt' file has this values:

```
0,4
2,5
4,6
6,7
8,8
10,9
12,10
```

But when I run it, I get this result:

[image]

Comment: Your data are _strings_. You need to convert them to integers.

Comment: Now that I realize, also the yaxis is shown disordered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use `int` instead `str` in axis:

```
for x in lines:
    t, m = x.split(',')
    time.append(int(t))
    ms.append(int(m))
```

Answer (score 0):

You may also want to try https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html

```
t, m = np.loadtxt('pings.txt', delimiter=',', unpack=True)
```